# How to use LSTM layers in CSV

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, bidirectional

I am try to make a project in which farming advice are generated based on weather condition on a specific district. I have a sample dataset for now, as shown below.

| state | district | month | rainfall | max_temp | min_temp | max_rh | min_rh | wind_speed | advice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orissa | Kendrapada | february | 0.0 | 34.6 | 19.4 | 88.2 | 29.6 | 12.0 | chances of foot rot disease in paddy crop; apply urea at 3 weeks after transplanting at active tillering stage for paddy;...... |
| Jharkhand | Saraikela Kharsawan | february | 0 | 35.2 | 16.6 | 29.4 | 11.2 | 3.6 | provide straw mulch and go for intercultural operations to avoid moisture losses from soil; chance of leaf blight disease in potato crop; ....... |

I want to use this dataset to generate advice for farmers based on weather conditions.

I have tokenized the advice columns and also converted them to tensor. I am unsure about which keras layers to use for model. The shape of each tensors in advice columns is TensorShape([150]). I need to train it so that it could generate texts. I know I should use Bidirectional LSTM, but how?

Please tell me which layers should I use and how to arrange them.

Answer (score 1):

Use Keras Sequential model to implement the above problem.
Firstly, encode your input data
Read csv file into dataframe, apply the labelencoder to get `x_train`, `y_train` and `x_test`, `y_test`. Follow the sample code, change according to your feature selection and requirement,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df_train = pd.read_csv("sampledata.csv")
df_train['wind_speed'] = LabelEncoder.fit_transform(df_train['wind_speed'])
x_train = df_train.values

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim = 4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='nadam')
```

Experiment with Dense layer and Bilstm layer. Make sure input data shape is proper

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25, batch_size=25)

pred = model.predict(x_test)
```